# Android instrumented test - test resource not resolved

Tags: android, android-espresso

I want to have `androidTest` resources specific to each app flavor.  I found an answer on this site that indicated you can just make a resource directory `androidTestFlavorName` and it will be managed like all the other resources.  So I have a directory `app/src/androidTestFlavorName/res/values` and a file `strings.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="test_sec_code">aStringValue</string>
</resources>
```

I have a test class `app/src/androidTest/java/com/company/package/StartupTest.kt`.  In that class:

`val code = context.getString(R.string.test_sec_code)`

`test_sec_code` is red, so the IDE doesn't like it, and the compiler reports: `Unresolved reference: test_sec_code`

My selected build variant is `flavorNameDebug`.  So am I setting up these resources wrong, or is my goal not possible?

Edit:
I tried putting the resource in `app/src/androidTest/res/values/strings.xml` and it can't be found there either.  Surely there must be a way to define test resources right?  Hello, is this thing on?